# sap.m.StepInput, how to disable (increment or decrement )value continuously on longpress, SAPUI5 Library we are using is 1.71.50

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, sapui5, sap-fiori

When we press the StepInput Increment Button, and keep on pressing, the value keep on increase, but we want, when we press StepInput Increment Button, eventhough we keep on pressing only one value should increase, inorder to increase another value we have to press again,
This is the same incase of decrement button also
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNYDm.png)

for this I tried, when you click on the Increment or decrement button, onmousedown event(FocusIn), in that I called blur() function, to focusOut of button, this was working as expected in 1.61 UI5 version,the value in the StepInput button will increase only onetime,eventhough you keep on pressing,to increment again you need to press again, but not in 1.71.50, In 1.71.50, blur() gets executed, but yet focusOut of button not happening and value in the StepInput button keeps increasing, still we release the button, when we actually release the button,then focusOut happening, Could anyone help on this

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the source code of sap.m.StepInput you can see, that the internal property `_btndown` plays a role in the "hold mouse button".
You can try to override that to stop the increase.
Something like:

```
var oStepInput = this.byId("StepInputId");
var oIcon = this.byId("StepInputId-incrementBtn");
oIcon.addEventDelegate({
    onmousedown: function (e) {
        oStepInput._btndown = false;
    }
});
```